# Waterline associations, change foreign key?

Tags: foreign-keys, associations, sails.js, waterline

The latest waterline now supports associations. Here is an example of a one-to-many

```
// A user may have many pets
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'user',
  connection: 'local-postgresql',

  attributes: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',

    // Add a reference to Pets
    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
});

var Pet = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'pet',
  connection: 'local-postgresql',

  attributes: {
    breed: 'string',
    type: 'string',
    name: 'string',

    // Add a reference to User
    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
});
```

This creates a field called `owner` on the pet collection. This would be fine except for working with an existing DB. which calls it's foreign key `owner_id`.

Is there anyway to override the field name used in the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the column name used for any model attribute by setting the [`columnName`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Models.md#columnname) property:

```
  attributes: {
    breed: 'string',
    type: 'string',
    name: 'string',

    // Add a reference to User
    owner: {
      columnName: 'owner_id',
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
```

Note also that when defining a model in Sails, you shouldn't extend from Waterline directly, but simply save the model file in `/api/models` with the appropriate name, e.g. `User.js`:

```
module.exports = {

   attributes: {
      breed: 'string',
      type: 'string',
      name: 'string',

      // Add a reference to User
      owner: {
         model: 'user',
         columnName: 'owner_id'
      }
   }
}
```

and let Sails / Waterline handle the identity and connection for you unless you really want to override the defaults.

Comment: That code was copied from the waterline docs. My models don't extend from waterline. But I did wonder if that was needed at one point so thanks for the additional info.

Comment: The Waterline docs are really intended for using Waterline outside of Sails; for Sails v0.10 you can use the [model docs on the web site](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/Models/Models.html).

Comment: Oh WOW!...I didn't know you could go to http://beta.sailsjs.org!!!

I've been scrounging for docs everywhere....Thank you!